# Efficient combination of a large number of affinity calls in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

We would like to compute on a large, partition-able dataset or 'products' in Ignite (100.000+ products, each linked to a large amount of extra data in different caches). We require several use cases:

1) Launch a compute job, limited to a large number (100's) of products, with a strong focus on responsiveness (<200ms). We can use the product ID as an affinity key to collocate all extra data with the products. But `affinityRun` only allows a single key to be specified, which would mean we need to launch 100's of compute jobs. Ideally we would be able to do an affinityRun on the entire set of product IDs at once, and let Ignite distribute the compute job to the relevant nodes, but we struggle to find a way to do this. (The compute job would then use local queries only on those compute nodes.)

2) Launch a compute job over the entire space of products in an efficient manner. We could launch the compute job on each compute node and use local queries, but that would no longer give us the benefits of falling back to backup partitions in case a primary partition is unavailable. This is an extreme case of problem number 1, just with a huge (all) number of product IDs as input.

We've been brainstorming about this for a while now, but it seems like we're missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version of `affinityRun` that takes a [partition number as a parameter](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCompute.html#affinityRunAsync-java.util.Collection-int-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteRunnable-). Distribute your task per partition and each node on the receiving end will be processing data residing in that partition number (just run a scan query for the partition). In case of failure, you'll just restart the process for a partition and can filter out already processed items with a custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Affinity job is nothing but the one which execute on the data node where key/value resides.
There are several ways to send job to particular node and not only affinity key. for example, you can send based on consistentID and in 2.4.10(if I remember correctly), they added way to query backup explicitly.
Regarding your scenario, I can think of below solution-

```
 SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery("select productID from CacheTable").setLocal(true);
```

You can prepare affinity job with above SQL where you will select all products(from that node only) and iterate over them and do all queries locally only to get all products information like this. Send that job to required node and do your computation and reduce the result and return to client.